# Is it possible to invoke a JS function from a different thread?

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, internet-explorer, com

I'm trying to make 2 different browsers communicate with each other through native code host (C++) using JS window.external.

The syntax is something like:

on destination.js:

```
window.external.register("dest", eventCallbak);  
function eventCallback(senderID, data) {  
    alert("message recieved from " + senderID + " with data of " + data);  
}
```

on source.js:

```
window.external.sendMsg("source", "dest", "Hello dest! this is source...");
```

I've managed to do so synchronously, by saving the `eventCallback` parameter, save it as an `IDispatch` and invoke it when asked (all in the same thread). no problems there.

The troubles begin when trying to do so asynchronously, meaning - saving the `eventCallback` as an `IDispatch` on one thread, and invoke it later on in another thread, causes the invoke method fail with `HRESULT` of `E_UNEXPECTED`.

Any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two browser instances use different instances of JS VM. 
You cannot in general to take one object from one VM/heap and pass it to another VM/heap.

So you will need to invent some kind of marshaling here.

Comment: Yeah, Eventually I used CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream to solve it. 
Thanks !